# SQL where query to a first row of IN condition

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN count(_days) > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'No' END) as availability 
  FROM ( 
        SELECT count(roomTypeDay2.room_type_id) as _days  
          FROM room_type_day as roomTypeDay2 
     LEFT JOIN room_type as roomType2 on roomTypeDay2.room_type_id = roomType2.id  
         WHERE roomType2.accommodation_id=3 
           AND roomTypeDay2.date IN ( '2018-06-09 00:00:00','2018-06-10 00:00:00','2018-06-11 00:00:00')  
      GROUP BY roomTypeDay2.room_type_id  
        HAVING COUNT(roomTypeDay2.room_type_id) = 3 
       ) as disponible
```

This works fine, but now, I want to filter if the first date row (2018-06-09 00:00:00) have

> "min_night_stay <= 3 and release_days <=2"

parameters, but I don't know how doing it.

I try adding these lines to a query:

> AND (roomTypeDay2.date = '2018-06-09 00:00:00' and
>   roomTypeDay2.min_night_stay <= 3 AND roomTypeDay2.release_days <= 2)

But this is not correct query.

**UDPATE**

```
 SELECT (CASE WHEN count(_days) > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'No' END) as availability 
   FROM ( 
        SELECT count(roomTypeDay2.room_type_id) as _days  
          FROM room_type_day as roomTypeDay2 
     LEFT JOIN room_type as roomType2 on roomTypeDay2.room_type_id = roomType2.id  
           AND roomType2.accommodation_id=3 
         WHERE roomTypeDay2.date IN ( '2018-06-09 00:00:00','2018-06-10 00:00:00','2018-06-11 00:00:00')  
      GROUP BY roomTypeDay2.room_type_id  
        HAVING COUNT(roomTypeDay2.room_type_id) = 3 
         ) as disponible
```

---

## Solution

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN count(_days) > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'No' END) as availability 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT count(roomTypeDay2.room_type_id) as _days  
        FROM room_type_day as roomTypeDay2  
        LEFT JOIN room_type as roomType2 on roomTypeDay2.room_type_id = roomType2.id 
        WHERE roomType2.accommodation_id=3 
        AND roomTypeDay2.num_rooms_available > 0  
        AND (roomTypeDay2.date = '2018-06-12 00:00:00' AND roomTypeDay2.min_night_stay <= 2 AND roomTypeDay2.release_days <= 2 )
        OR roomTypeDay2.date IN ( '2018-06-13 00:00:00','2018-06-14 00:00:00')  
        GROUP BY roomTypeDay2.room_type_id  
        HAVING COUNT(roomTypeDay2.room_type_id) = 3 
    ) as disponible
```

Comment: Use windowed functions like row_number over partition

Comment: That LEFT JOIN executes as a regular INNER JOIN. Move the roomType2 conditions from WHERE to IN to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Typo. IN should be ON in my previous comment.

Comment: Hi @jarlh , in this case, do you mean to change "WHERE" to "AND" in this case? Can you write a example please? Thank you

Comment: Keep the roomTypeDay2 condition in the WHERE clause. Simply move the roomType2 condition to the ON clause. (Use AND.)

Comment: Hi @jarlh , I update my code as you say but this doesnt solve my issue. I don't konw how to add condition to select if date IN (date1,date2,date3) and date1 have min_night_stay and release_days conditions.

Comment: maybe you can use  " roomTypeDay2.date between '2018-06-09' and DATE_ADD('2018-06-09' , INTERVAL 2 DAY) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE roomTypeDay2.date IN ('2018-06-09 00:00:00',
                            '2018-06-10 00:00:00',
                            '2018-06-11 00:00:00')
```

Now for the first date you want additional criteria. Use `AND` and `OR`with parentheses for this:

```
WHERE 
(
  roomTypeDay2.date = '2018-06-09 00:00:00'
  AND
  roomTypeDay2.min_night_stay <= 3 
  AND
  roomTypeDay2.release_days <= 2
)
OR
roomTypeDay2.date IN ('2018-06-10 00:00:00','2018-06-11 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thank you "Thorsten Kettner", This solution is perfect. With the "HAVING" condoition, it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT
  (
    CASE WHEN count(_days) > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'No' END
  ) as availability
from
  (
    SELECT
      count(roomTypeDay2.room_type_id) as _days
    FROM
      room_type_day as roomTypeDay2
      LEFT JOIN room_type as roomType2 on roomTypeDay2.room_type_id = roomType2.id
      AND roomType2.accommodation_id = 3
    WHERE
      roomTypeDay2.date IN ('2018-06-10 00:00:00', '2018-06-11 00:00:00')
    GROUP BY
      roomTypeDay2.room_type_id
    HAVING
      COUNT(roomTypeDay2.room_type_id) = 3
    union
    SELECT
      count(roomTypeDay2.room_type_id) as _days
    FROM
      room_type_day as roomTypeDay2
      LEFT JOIN room_type as roomType2 on roomTypeDay2.room_type_id = roomType2.id
      AND roomType2.accommodation_id = 3
    WHERE
      roomTypeDay2.date = '2018-06-09 00:00:00'
      and roomTypeDay2.min_night_stay <= 3
      AND roomTypeDay2.release_days <= 2
    GROUP BY
      roomTypeDay2.room_type_id
    HAVING
      COUNT(roomTypeDay2.room_type_id) = 3
  ) disponible
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for posting the query but when I execute it, returns me this exception: "every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Thank you, now if I add "sum" to a CASE, I get "invalid use of group function". :(

Comment: count(sum(_days)) - i have used this,first sum the days and then use case statement on count of it

Comment: I understand what you want to do but if I add sum like you are adding, "count(sum(_days))", I get "invalid use of group function"  error. I try changing the second selects name to "_days2" and in a case doing count(_days+_days2) but I get "unknown column '_days2' in field list".

Comment: is it possible for yoy to provide sample data at sqlfiddle.com or https://www.db-fiddle.com/ ?

Comment: Yes, here you have my tables example data: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/czS11my3wTYYodtmyLemFM/0 
There is no rooms available in  "2018/06/11", then if you try to find from 09 to 12 for example, the query have to return "NO",. THen if you select from 12 to 14, the query have to return "YES"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172890/discussion-between-kedar-limaye-and-argoitz).